# C# Performance: set every time again or check if value is already right and only set if its wrong?

Tags: c#, performance

Hey Is it more performant to write this:

```
Method_That_Is_Getting_Repeated()
{
   if(var1 <0)
   {
      var2 = 'l';
   }
   else if(var1 >0)
   {
      var = 'r';
   }
}
```

Or this:

```
Method_That_Is_Getting_Repeated()
{
   if(var1 <0)
   {
      if(var2 != 'l')
      var2 = 'l';
   }
   else if(var1 >0)
   {
      if(var2 != 'r')
      var = 'r';
   }
}
```

The var2 will already have the right value in many cases, so that it wouldnt have to be set again.

In other words: Does the if statement cost more/less time/performance to be executed than initializing a variable like float,int,char,double,bool?

Comment: Is that a bottleneck in your application? If not, go for readability.

Comment: I would say using the if's might be slower.

Comment: no it is no bottleneck. I just use code like this really often and asked myself this question pretty often.

Comment: All the more reason to go with the most obvious, readable, short implementation. To stop asking yourself this question, get a better understanding of what might affects performance and what most likely won't ;-)

Comment: That is what i am doing at the moment :P. And i thought before, that an if statement would load one value in the register, compare it to the other value in the ram and setting a flag (1 or 0) afterwards that will affect the EIP. But i am pretty new to C and assembler so i am/was not sure about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no danger in reseting a `char` field to the same value.  It's an atomic operation, simple operation that won't be observable in a meaningful way. The `if` statement though is a branching operation which is *genarally* speaking slower than a direct set because of the possibility of a bad prediction.  Now this is nothing I would never design my program around but given that there is no real downside to setting the field to the same value why bother with the `if` at all?

Comment: "because of the possibility of a bad prediction" - what does that mean?

Comment: @WillJenkins the possibility that the CPU predicted the wrong path on the branching operation and hence had to reset the pipeline to sum degree

Answer (score 1):

These operations will end up on the stack and be lightning fast. The difference in performance will be negligible (in the magnitude of milliseconds difference over MILLIONS of operations I'd bet) compared to other, larger parts of your app. Make it as maintainable and readable as possible, and return to re-evaluate once these lines become the largest offenders of your performance profiling reports (which I assure you they will never be unless this is literally the only thing that your application does).

Comment: If you're going to talk about low level performance tuning, please do it right. (1) The stack is *slow* in this world ;-) Register storage is where it's at. (2) It depends on what `var1` and `var2` are. If they're members of a reference type, it's unlikely to be on the CLR stack or on the CPU stack, let alone registers. This would be an optimization that is possible (and does happen in the wild), but only in very narrow circumstances and I'm not sure whether .NET implements it. Most likely they'd be in RAM.

Comment: @delnan good points. I didn't want to get into OP codes for registers, haha. Similarly, I assumed his char type which would be on the stack, but you're right that reference types would be heaped. I guess I meant the *instructions* for the if-else vs set would both be on the stack making it reasonably painless.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `Method_That_Is_Getting_Repeated` version2 is poor compared in version1 in terms of readability and also performance. I believe assigning a `char` is faster than comparing it.

I did some benchmarks some time ago which shown me direct assignment is better than comparisons. So measure your performance yourself and see which is better.

Answer (score 0):

The second option has a higher complexity, so is likely to be less performant. It's also less readable. I would not worry much about it unless it is shown to be a cause of slow performance though.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity

Comment: Cyclomatic complexity is no no way related to performance at all.